# Do I need to copy RootCA in machine 2 & 3's trusted root

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, self-signed-certificate

- I have 3 machines in domain and where I choose Machine1 to host asp.net web api application.
- I have create my own CA RootCA and put in Machine1's trusted root.
- then I issued one more certificate X with Machine1 fully qualified domain name from RootCA.
- I put certificate X in Machine1's Personal root.
- I bind my asp.net web api app with certificate X.
- If I browse to my asp.net web api, it's running fine and NO certificate error.
- Now when I am trying to browse my asp.net web api from Machine2 & Machine3, I am getting certificate error.

[image]

- If I copied RootCA certificate to both Machine2 & Machine3's trusted store, then NO certificate error.

My questions,

- It this required to copy RootCA certificate to both Machine2 & Machine3's trusted store?
- Can I eliminate this steps? perhaps I don't want to install any certificate in Machine2 & Machine3. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "browse my asp.net web api from Machine2 & Machine3"? And where/how do you get the certificate error. Please add the full error messages you get to your question and include how you access which API from where to where and who is consuming which API (from where).

Comment: @Progman, I edited my question. I am using chrome browser to access web api. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It this required to copy RootCA certificate to both Machine2 & Machine3's trusted store?

Yes, otherwise the machines won't be able to assert whether to trust the certificate(s) issued by it.

> can I eliminate this steps?

No, but since they're domain members you can [automate distribution of the root certificate via Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy) by configuring the following setting in a GPO that targets machine 2 and 3:

```
Path: Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies
Setting: Trusted Root Certification Authorities
```

Comment: Thanks much for the confirmation